# How to change color in CSS with PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

In my CSS file a div has following property: `background-color: blue;`

Is it possible to change the color with PHP?

HTML:

```
<div id="div_id" class="div_class">
    Text
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div_class {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

PHP:

```
if($variable == "Black")
{
    ... *change css color to black* ...
}
```

Comment: `<div id="div_id" class="div_class" style="background-color: black;">` or add additional class like `<div id="div_id" class="div_class div_class_black_bg">`

Comment: Why would you use PHP for this?JS and CSS would work fine

Comment: Are you using forms?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Yes It could be done with JS but I need to get the information which color the div gets (from the php variable)

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW No :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by in-line style or additional class.

In-line:

```
<?php
    if($variable == "Black")
      echo '<div id="div_id" style="background-color:black" class="div_class">
        Text
      </div>';
?>
```

Additional class:

```
<?php
    if($variable == "Black")
      echo '<div id="div_id" class="div_class backgroundcolor-black">
        Text
      </div>';
?>
```

Your css looks like:

```
.div_class.backgroundcolor-black {
    background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: Vote for the "Additional class" solution.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just append the variable to the class and add an override style:

```html
<div id="div_id" class="div_class div_class--<?php echo strtolower($variable); ?>"  >
    Text
</div>
```

```css
.div_class {
  background-color: blue;
}

.div_class--black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: if the user can pass the value via the url, this solution will be open to xss.

Comment: @Vidal There is no mention that this is a `$_GET` variable

Comment: yes but you are not doing any sanitizing on the variable **$variable**, and as I mention if the user can pass the value via url. just a note.

Comment: @Vidal the sanitizing should have happened from whatever changed the `$_GET` into `$variable` so why should I show that in my answer - even when the OP has not said this comes from the url directly - you are poking holes in an answer  to a question that has not been asked

Comment: my friend, you haven't read my first comment...**IF** THE USER CAN PASS THE VALUE VIA THE URL. if the user can't then is **not suppose** to be an issue. I always sanitize and take measures of small details.

Answer (score 2):

**CSS** :

```
.div_class{
    background-color: blue;
}
.div_red{
    background-color: red;
}
.div_green{
    background-color: green;
}
```

We can change color using below code

**PHP:**

```
$class = 'div_class';
if($variable == "red")
{
    $class = 'div_red';
} else if($variable == "green") {
    $class = 'div_green';
}

<div id="div_id" class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
    Text
</div>
```

I hope above will help.

Answer (score 1):

`<div id="div_id" 
class="<?= ($variable=='black')?'div_class_black':'div_class"?>">
    Text
</div>`

**In css:**

```
.div_class{
    background-color: blue;
}

.div_class_black{
   background-color: black;
}
```

You have to create two classes

Comment: How does the ternary operator looks like when the are 3 oder 4 colors?

Comment: for multiple colors                                                                                               
 $colors = ['red','black','blue','yellow'];

if (in_array($variable, $colors)){
 echo "div_class_".$variable;
}else{
 echo "div_class_";
}

Answer (score 1):

Define 2 clases

```
.div_class_blue{
   background-color: blue;
}
.div_class_black{
   background-color: #000;
}
```

on the PHP you can do a if/else with ternary operator.

```
<div id="div_id" class="<?php ($variable=="black")?"div_class_black":"div_class_blue" ?>"  >
    Text
</div>
```

[PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: How does the ternary operator looks like when the are 3 oder 4 colors?

Comment: you can stack them, but in that case for easy reading people use regular if/else statements